# Seagate 3TB ST3000DM001 hard drive not recognized by Linux, causes fdisk to hang

Tags: linux, hard-drive, usb-storage, usb-3, gpt

I'm running Kubuntu 12.04. I have a brand new, never used Seagate 3TB ST3000DM001 hard drive. It's an internal drive. I installed it in a USB enclosure.

When I connect it to my PC, nothing happens automatically. When I run `sudo fdisk -l`, fdisk hangs (without reporting this drive) until I disconnect this drive from the USB port. `blkid` won't report it either.

I tried connecting it to both USB 2.0 and USB 3.0 ports on my PC. I got the same result either way. I tried two different USB enclosures with the same result.

If I take the same drive, same enclosure and connect it to a Windows 7 laptop, it is recognized automatically as a USB mass storage device.

I want to format the drive (probably ext4) and copy files to it. I have another drive, also in a USB enclosure, that is connected via USB 3.0 to this PC and it works fine. It's a 2.0 TB Samsung HDD. I plan to copy files from the 2TB to the 3TB drive, once I get this issue resolved.

My motherboard is an Asus P8B WS LGA1155/ Intel C206/ Quad CrossFireX/ SATA3&USB3.0/ A&2GbE/ ATX. Linux kernel is 3.2.

dmesg output from multiple connection attempts:

```
[43595.344419] usb 2-1.1: new high-speed USB device number 4 using ehci_hcd
[43605.570093] Initializing USB Mass Storage driver...
[43605.570435] scsi6 : usb-storage 2-1.1:1.0
[43605.570665] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[43605.570673] USB Mass Storage support registered.
[43606.566344] scsi 6:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ST3000DM 001-9YN166       CC4C PQ: 0 ANSI: 0
[43606.568089] sd 6:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
[43606.569510] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Very big device. Trying to use READ CAPACITY(16).
[43606.569884] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] 5860533168 512-byte logical blocks: (3.00 TB/2.72 TiB)
[43606.572883] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[43606.572892] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 23 00 00 00
[43606.574012] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page present
[43606.574024] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[43606.574857] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Very big device. Trying to use READ CAPACITY(16).
[43606.576733] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page present
[43606.576740] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[43636.913914] usb 2-1.1: reset high-speed USB device number 4 using ehci_hcd
[43667.845759] usb 2-1.1: reset high-speed USB device number 4 using ehci_hcd
[43674.904939] usb 2-1.1: USB disconnect, device number 4
[43674.912044] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Unhandled error code
[43674.912055] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb]  Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[43674.912065] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] CDB: Read(10): 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
[43674.912085] end_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 0
[43674.912094] quiet_error: 6 callbacks suppressed
[43674.912099] Buffer I/O error on device sdb, logical block 0
[43674.912242] ldm_validate_partition_table(): Disk read failed.
[43674.912295] Dev sdb: unable to read RDB block 0
[43674.912377]  sdb: unable to read partition table
[43674.912718] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] READ CAPACITY failed
[43674.912731] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb]  Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[43674.912739] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Sense not available.
[43674.913479] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page present
[43674.913487] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[43674.913492] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
```

Comment: what kernel are you running? run `uname -a` and post the output here

Comment: This sounds like a GPT compatibility problem.

Comment: 3.2.0-20-generic #33-Ubuntu SMP Tue Mar 27 16:42:26 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/283403/3tb-sata-hard-drives-into-an-old-linux-system

Comment: @techie007 - I'm not booting from the drive and I don't have an old OS or very old hardware. My motherboard has USB 3.0.

Comment: Can you confirm that you are able to transfer files to the drive under Windows 7, or that the drive works with your internal SATA ports under Linux?

Comment: @DragonLord, Linux supports GPT just fine.  I'm using it on several computers, including one that doesn't have EFI.

Comment: @Breakthrough--I didn't format the drive yet and I don't plan to format with NTFS anyway. I also prefer not take my PC apart and mount the drive internally. But if I have to do that, it will certainly answer my question. I asked here in order to avoid having to take my PC apart.

Comment: What is the output of `dmesg` after you plug it in?

Comment: @Keith--I added dmesg output to original question. Thanks for the suggestion. I should have done that from the beginning.

Comment: What's the block size of that disK? Is it a new 4k block device? I think it is, but kernel is assuming 512 byte blocks. BTW, you might try a newer kernel, ubuntu is a bit old. Linux 3.3.1 just came out. Compile and try that one.

Comment: @Keith--from Seagate.com I'm not sure what it means, but this is all I can find: "Your no-hassle transition to 4K sectors. Are you worried about moving to Advanced Format 4K sector technology? You don’t have to be with Barracuda drives. Seagate SmartAlign™ technology makes this transition a snap."

Comment: UPDATE: I used another computer and connected the drive internally. I formatted it and checked every sector. It took around 36 hours and it finished successfully. I bought a new USB dock (http://www.sybausa.com/productInfo.php?iid=1108) with Maximum Capacity (per Bay) of 3TB. I plugged it in and it immediately locked up my desktop so hard that I had to turn the power off. :(

Comment: Seems a lot of hassle, trouble and time you've gone to avoid plugging it internally. Simply try it (use a livecd if you're worried about your existing drives & unplug them). If it detects, partitions and formats internally then it'll be a compatibility issue between the 4K sector size/caddy/USB/Linux (choose whichever you wish). But until you try it internally you can't rule out a faulty drive/interface (the Windows 7 detection may have been a fluke, did you run any kind of copy/scan/check on it?)

Comment: @HaydnWVN - I guess you didn't read my comment just above yours. All your questions are touched upon there.

Comment: Sorry, maybe i needed to be more concise - the fault is probably your caddy and Linux compatibility.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Seagate 3TB ST3000DM001 hard drive ***will*** work in Linux (I'm using Kubuntu 12.04) with USB 3.0 and an external enclosure. I had to initially format the drive using gdisk while it was mounted internally. Then, with the right external enclosure, simply plug it in and it is recognized automatically. The file manager shows 2.7TB free. It acts like a usual USB hard drive. Everything is typical and there are no problems.

The problems could come from trying to use fdisk or using a drive enclosure that doesn't support drives larger than 2 TB or possibly from some incompatibilities.

I did get it working with the Syba USB dock (sybausa.com/productInfo.php?iid=1108) with Maximum Capacity (per Bay) of 3TB. I'm not sure if I'll stick with this dock, but it is working.

Answer (score 3):

Confirmed. However, the choice of dock is of paramount importance. The first dock I got, a startech unidock2u, showed the same errors, even when I formatted the drive first, and despite being advertised compatible with drives up to 4TB and Linux. The post above is the only one I've found that recounts success using a 3TB with Linux. And happily the Syba mentioned does work as described. I found it online as "Syba CL-ENC50038 Dual Mode SATA III HDD Duplicator and Docking Station" but the picture shows it labelled/branded "Connectland", and that is what I have also. I first plugged in my 3TB Seagate (ST3000DM001) to a motherboard SATA port that is 3TB capable and formatted the drive. (I did not think to try it first without formatting.) But it does work afterwards perfectly in the dock. Two 3.5" 3TB drives at the same time work OK also.

I am using ST3000DM001 3TB drives and smaller drives with a Connectland DOCK-3UBT3 (same as Syba above) on Debian Wheezy/Sid, kernel 3.2.0. I expect it would also work on CentOS 6 but, I have not tested it yet. My reasoning is that the USB errors I had gotten with a 3TB drive had been identical on CentOS (2.6.32) and Debian (3.2.0).