# How to partition and format a new HDD when it is connected via USB 3.0 (Linux)?

Tags: linux, usb, partitioning, external-hard-drive, formatting

I just received a new unformatted 2.5" hard disk (1 TB) and an external USB 3.0 enclosure to use with my laptop (Thinkpad). I'm running Kubuntu 12.04 on my laptop.

How do I access and format this HDD when it is connected via USB? I have installed it into the external enclosure and connected it to my laptop and it is powered on, yet it does not show up with either `sudo fdisk -l` or `blkid`. The only device that shows up is /dev/sda.

The USB HDD also fails to show up in the GUI Partition Manager too, unsurprisingly.

When I plug the USB HDD in, I get message like this:

```
attached enclosure device
attached scsi generic sg2 type 13
uas_eh_abort_handler tag 0
uas_eh_device_reset_handler tag 0
...
reset high speed USB device number 5
Device offlined - not ready after error recovery
rejecting I/O to offline device
```

I [ran into a similar problem before](https://superuser.com/questions/409742/seagate-3tb-st3000dm001-hard-drive-not-recognized-by-linux-causes-fdisk-to-hang) on a desktop and the only solution I found was to connect the HDD to an internal sata port and format the disk. Then I could use it while connected via USB. Currently I am traveling and I only have access to my laptop.

Assuming I cannot connect the disk internally on my computer and I don't have access to any other computer to do the same, how can I accomplish this task? **I need to initially partition and format the disk (ext4) via USB.**

Update: the drive+enclosure are recognized in Windows. Windows allowed me to partition and format the drive.

Comment: show output of `cat /proc/partitions` to see if kernel sees the disk

Comment: I gave up. There is some incompatibility between Linux, the drive enclosure, my laptop and USB 3.0. The drive+enclosure could be recognized and formatted in Windows, but nothing I tried would work in Linux. I ended up using a USB 2.0 enclosure and I got it to work in Linux. It sucks that Linux still has so many problems with USB 3.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a different USB enclosure and I got it to work in Linux.

I know this isn't a product review site, but in this situation my problem was hardware incompatibility and I had to waste money buying two products to get one that worked. So I'll share the details to save others the problem.

The [Rocketfish Rf-hd3025 USB 3.0 2.5" Sata Hard Drive Enclosure](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004MEZ5IM), which is a very nice looking product, appears to be incompatible with Linux (at least it does not work with Ubuntu 12.04 and a Thinkpad laptop). It costs about US$20 and it looks great, but I could not get it to work in Linux. (It worked with Windows.) It also uses a properietary split USB cable that takes up more bulk, which can be important if you are lacking space in your travel bag.

The [USB 3.0 2.5 Inch SATA III Drive Enclosure Case](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0070MCQBW) does not exhibit the same impressive looking design, but it is smaller (which I like) and appears solidly made. Most importantly, it works with Linux. It is fully powered by USB which is very handy. It also uses a standard USB cable. It also costs about US$20. YMMV.